# Где в Android Studio задается количество пробелов для форматирования?

Tags: android, android-studio

Иногда попадается файл с нестандартным форматированием. Тогда Android Studio спрашивает, изменить ли количество символов в отступе, и запоминает ответ. В результате некоторые файлы отличаются от остальных. Где посмотреть настройку для этих файлов и ее изменить?

Comment: Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> Java